# BroadcastReceiver - Inner class vs function returning object?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, inner-classes

I used `BroadcastReceiver` in almost all activities to connect to a background `Service` in android and I implemented it as **inner class**es first due to specific requirement for each `Activity` and then I tried it with function calling which returns a `BroadcastReceiver` object with same implementation. So, I was thinking which approach is better.

Note: A background `Service` continuously sends broadcasts upon updates and if any `Activity` which has receiver will use it.

Comment: do you not have an application class?

Comment: I tend not to extend the application class as it is a bad practice, and I don't seem to understand why application class refer to this question?